# Is there a way to inquire the port forwarding done by Android Studio?

Tags: debugging, android-studio, adb, portforwarding, ddms

If Android Studio is running on my development machine, when I launch the app on a device from the command line using this command:

> $ adb shell am start -D -n  -a ...

Android Studio would immediately forward a port on the local host (8600 and up) to the jdwp port of the app, so that the debugger in Android Studio could debug the app if necessary.

Now, if, say, I would like to use a 3rd party debugger (rather than the debugger in Android Studio) to debug the app, I will need to connect that debugger to the port forwarded by Android Studio to that app to get the debugging to work.

**My question: How can I determine what that port is?**

Here are a couple of things I've tried (to no avail):

1. > $ adb forward --list

   Alas, the forwarding done by Android Studio isn't shown.
2. > $ adb forward tcp:9010 jdwp:

   Connecting the debugger to 9010 failed, probably because the jdwp port is already locked up by Android Studio's port forwarding.
3. I can turn on DDMS and see the port assigned to the app. But what I need is an API or text output so that I can get that info programmatically?

You insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the open ports on you pc and filter which is being used by android studio, Hope you get what you are looking for.
In windows-

> [netstat -aon](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netstat.mspx?mfr=true)

In linux:-

[netstat -lptu](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat)

Please check the options for above command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Rilwan. netstat can indeed give me the list of ports used by Android Studio, but it can't tell which port maps to which app.